# Initializing bootstrap-markdown with JavaScript and customizing the options

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, markdown

I'm trying to use [bootstrap-markdown](https://github.com/toopay/bootstrap-markdown) and everything works fine except I can't call the plugin via JavaScript. For instance:

```
$("#content").markdownEditor({
                autofocus: false,
                savable: false,
                iconlibrary: 'fa',
                resize: 'vertical',
                additionalButtons: custom_buttons,  // an array defining custom commands
                onPreview: function (e) {
                    var content = e.getContent();
                    console.log('content', content);
                }
            });
```

Does anyone has any ideas what might be the case? Couldn't find anything useful on the web or repo's github page. And yes I've already included `markdown.js` and `to-markdown.js` which weren't mentioned in the docs at all but it was quick find anyway.

All I need now is to call the editor, add a couple of custom toolbar buttons (image upload, code block insert etc.) and be done with it.

Code snippets, links & live fiddles are much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, changing the order of script references fixed this.
Here's the order now:

- `lib/markdown.js`
- `lib/bootstrap-markdown.js`  ,
- `lib/to-markdown.js`

And here's my initialization:

```
$(function () {
    var custom_buttons = [[
        {
            name: "insertCode",
            data: [{
                name: "cmdInsertCode",
                toggle: "toggle",
                title: "Insert Code",
                icon: "fa fa-fire",
                callback: function (e) {
                    var selected = e.getSelection(),
                        content = e.getContent();
                    // e.replaceSelection(chunk);
                    // var cursor = selected.start;

                    //e.setSelection(cursor, cursor + chunk.length);

                    console.log('cmdInsertCode clicked');
                }
            }]
        }
    ]];

    $("#content").markdown({
        autofocus: false,
        savable: false,
        iconlibrary: 'glyph',
        resize: 'vertical',
        additionalButtons: custom_buttons,
        onShow: function (e) {
            console.warn('e:editor shown');
        }
    });
});
```

Kudos :godmode: